# How to map my json path into cosmos db from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add entries into my cosmosdb using Azure Data Factory - However i am not able to choose the right collection as Azure Data Factory can only see the top level of the database.

[image]
Is there any funny syntax for choosing which collection to pick from Cosmos DB SQL API? - i've tried doing, entities[0] and entities['tasks'] but none of them seem to work

[image]

[image]

The new entries are inserted as we see in the red box, how do i get the entries into the entries collection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you means put the json to the tasks? Can you explan your requirements?:)

Comment: @BowmanZhu yes that's correct, i need to put the json into tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

[image]

**Original Answer:**

If the requirement you mentioned in the comments is what you need, then it is possible. For example, to put JSON data into an existing ‘tasks’ item, you only need to use the upsert method, and the source json data has the same id as the ‘tasks’ item.

This is the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#azure-cosmos-db-sql-api-as-sink

The random letters and numbers in your red box appear because you did not specify the document id.

Have a look of this:

[image]

By the way, if the tasks have partitional key, then you also need to specify.

Comment: How would i add these items with the tasks, there is no option to add it into the tasks id